# I am trying to load the data from Excel data (Currency formatted data) to SQL table with data type Number (28, 10) using SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis, format, currency

I am trying to load the data from Excel data (**Currency formatted data**) to SQL table with data type **Number (28, 10)** using **SSIS**. In the source system it has data like 10.123456789 but when I exported data to SQL Table data has getting saved with only 4 digits in the precision (10.1234). **I want to retrieve the original value.** 
Please share your thoughts and help me ?

Comment: What are the data types for the particular column in the source Excel file  connection? Are you doing any conversion tasks?

Comment: Are you using SQL-Server? IF so, please tag the question as such. As for the data type, you must mean `NUMERIC(28,10)`.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is reading it as currency which defaults to 4 decimals. My suggestion would be to convert the Excel to CSV so you can define each column with the proper data type.

To my knowledge there is no way to control the incoming data types in an Excel Connection manager. I would love someone to prove you can to me as I find Excel is a nightmare source.

Comment: in ssis data conversion tool is also usefull

Answer (score 0):

You may need to adjust the settings in SSIS.

Open the connection manager for the excel sheet, and click on "advanced" in the list on the left-hand-side.
Select the column in question, and adjust the precision and scale accordingly
In your case, I believe that it would be: precision of 24 and scale of 10.

> Documentation on scale and precision: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

you can change your  data type in sql  to decimal (11,9) . So that your data 10.123456789 can come in as it is .

Comment: you don't get to determine data types when the source is Excel.